# XML highlighting of tag with < in the attribute

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting, xml

I'm still searching for an exising bug report on the [google prettify bug list page](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list) and I will add one if none exist, but I thought someone here might like to know as well.
It seems that XML attributes containing `<` break the syntax highlighting for just that line.  Check out the third line in the code from my answer to [Editing crontab remotely with ant sshexec doesn't not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028897/editing-crontab-remotely-with-ant-sshexec-doesnt-not-work/8029237#8029237):

```xml
<target name="remove-crontab">
    <echo message="Removing Crontab" />
    <sshexec host="${host}" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="crontab < /dev/null" trust="true" failonerror="false" />
</target>
```

Even when using: `<!-- language: lang-xml -->`

The bug is not showing in the code above as I am writing this question, so you might need to look at the SO post unless question previews just dont get prettified until the Q is posted..?

Comment: The bug is not in prettify, the bug is in the XML.  That is not a _valid_ XML file.  It should be encoded as a character entity (`&lt;`).

Comment: Oh, well, I learned something today! :)

Comment: Of course, highlighting doesnt matter much to the OP as long as the question is answered, but, out of curiousity, is there no way to *display* a `<` in an attribute inside a code format block (w/ highlighting).  Because `crontab &lt; /dev/null` just looks weird.

Comment: There isn't supposed to be a `<` in that location if it should be wellformed XML, so displaying `<` would just be misleading. `crontab &lt; /dev/null` might look wired to you, but `crontab < /dev/null` will look like broken XML to whatever program is supposed to process it. It's the same as with backslash escapes in strings. For example displaying `"ab"cd"` instead of `"ab\"cd"` won't do any good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML attributes with literal `<` in them also [break XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttValue), so that's not surprising.